# C# Linq Join Lambda (a key selector contains the other key selector)

Tags: c#, linq, join, key

Similar to an sql query "where a like '%b%' "

C# with .Net framework 4.6 doesn't accept this:

```
context.Table1
    .Join(
        context.Table2,
        table1 => table1.strStringContainsIntegers, // string (.net needs int, 
                                  //I need string that contains list of integers)
        table2 => table2.intInteger,                // integer
        (table1, table2) => new { table1.SomeField, table2.SomeField }
    ).Where(o=>o.table1.strStringContainsIntegers.Contains(table2.intInteger+"-"));
```

how can I join two tables/lists on one column(key selector 2) is contained in another column(key selector 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var query =
    context
        .Table1
        .SelectMany(table1 =>
            context
                .Table2
                .Where(table2 => table1.strStringContainsIntegers.Contains(table2.intInteger.ToString()))
                .Select(
                    table2 => new {table1.SomeField, table2.SomeField}));
```

LINQ will convert this to an SQL Join.